# How to write a Lambda Expression to select distinct words from list of sentences

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How to write lambda expression to get distinct words from the following list of sentences?

```
string[] famousquotes =
    {
        "Advertising is legalized lying",
        "Advertising is the greatest art form of the twentieth century"
    };

var distinctWords = famousquotes.Select(s => s.Split(' ')).
```

I want the output like

```
Advertising
is
legalized
lying
the 
greatest 
art 
form 
of
twentieth 
century
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var distinctWords = famousquotes
                         .SelectMany(s => 
                             s.Split(new []{' '}, 
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                         .Distinct();
```

Use SelectMany to get all underlying strings. then use Distinct which does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing fancy.A very simple trick :)

```
var result = String.Join(" ",famousquotes).Split(' ').Distinct();
```